# Using a Button to add Data to TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Is their anyway I can use a button to add "records" to a table view? Most of the examples i see online are reading in data from files and hard coding data into the code. I am making a record based program, and have not been able to come up with a solid way of doing this.

Is there a way to create an array that adds data to the columns? So when i add a record, i add it to an array then refresh the column?

I have seen this way of doing it:

```
 final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("Jacob", "Smith"), new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"), new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones"), new Person("Michael", "Brown"));
```

can someone explain this better? How can i add records real time everytime the user clicks the "save Button" it adds a record to the table.

controller:

```
package javafxapplication1;
import javafxapplication1.JavaFXApplication1;
import java.net.URL;
import static java.util.Collections.list;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;

/**
 *
 * @author KJ4CC
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {






    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TextField dateText;
    @FXML
    private TextField time;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> band;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> mode;
    @FXML
    private Button save;
     @FXML
     private Button Clear;
     @FXML
     private TableView logTable;
     @FXML
     private TableColumn dateTime,user,callSign,logBand,logMode,logLocation,logSent,logRx,logComment;



    public void saveButtonClick(){

        logTable.getItems().add(dateText.getText());


    }
    public void clearButtonClick(){
        dateText.setText("");
        time.setText("");


    }
    public void setTimeDate(){
       JavaFXApplication1 javaFXApp = new JavaFXApplication1();
       dateText.setText(javaFXApp.getDate());

    }

    public void setTime(){
       JavaFXApplication1 javaFXApp = new JavaFXApplication1();
       time.setText(javaFXApp.getTime());

    }
    @Override

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         ObservableList<String> bands = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "70CM",
        "2M",
        "6M",
        "10M",
        "11M",
        "12M",
        "15M",
        "20M",
        "30M",
        "40m",
        "60M",
        "80M",
        "160M"
    );
             ObservableList<String> modes = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        "Phone",
        "SSB",
        "CW",
        "PSK31",
        "Dgital Voice",
        "HellSchriber",
        "RTTY",
        "SSTV",
        "Satelight",
        "Packet",
        "Frequency Shift",
        "FM",
        "AM"
    );
        band.setItems(bands);
        band.setValue("70CM");
        mode.setItems(modes);
        mode.setValue("Phone");
    }    

}
```

Main:

```
package javafxapplication1;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController;

/**
 *
 * @author KJ4CC
 */
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {
     private ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private FXMLDocumentController initScene;
    private   DateFormat dtf;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();


    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public String getDate(){
        dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        Date dateobj = new Date();
        return dtf.format(dateobj);
    }
    public String getTime(){
         dtf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm;ss");
        Date dateobj = new Date();
        return dtf.format(dateobj);
    }
    public void addTable(TableView table,TextField dateText){




    }

}
```

FXML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="412.0" prefWidth="683.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController">
   <top>
      <VBox prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="543.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <MenuBar>
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
            <TableView fx:id="logTable" prefHeight="210.0" prefWidth="599.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="dateTIme" prefWidth="75.0" text="Date/Time" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="user" prefWidth="72.0" text="User" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="callSign" prefWidth="73.0" text="Call" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="logBand" prefWidth="64.0" text="Band" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="logMode" prefWidth="63.0" text="Mode" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="logLocation" prefWidth="112.0" text="Location" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="logSent" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="55.0" text="Sent " />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="logRx" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="63.0" text="Recived" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="logComment" prefWidth="103.0" text="Comment" />
              </columns>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="2.0" right="2.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <VBox prefHeight="188.0" prefWidth="673.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="625.0">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Date:" wrappingWidth="83.462890625">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" right="20.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
                  <Label onMouseClicked="#setTimeDate" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Time:" wrappingWidth="77.40625" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Call:" wrappingWidth="122.94921875">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Band:" wrappingWidth="96.443359375" />
                  <Label />
                  <Text layoutX="325.0" layoutY="23.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Mode:" wrappingWidth="99.443359375" />
                  <Text layoutX="524.0" layoutY="23.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Power: " wrappingWidth="55.724609375" />
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Location:" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="625.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField id="dateText" fx:id="dateText" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="94.0">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField fx:id="time" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="71.0">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField fx:id="call" layoutX="104.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="101.0">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="band" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="87.0">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="20.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ComboBox>
                  <ComboBox fx:id="mode" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="93.0">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ComboBox>
                  <TextField fx:id="power" layoutX="306.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="47.0">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField fx:id="location" layoutX="306.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="101.0" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="580.0">
               <children>
                  <Text fill="#14bdd7" onMouseClicked="#setTimeDate" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Use Current Date">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="20.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Text>
                  <Text fill="#14bdd7" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="23.0" onMouseClicked="#setTime" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Use Current Time" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="737.0">
               <children>
                  <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="48.0" text="Sent">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="46.0" text="Recived ">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="66.0" text="Comment" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="737.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField id="dateText" fx:id="sent" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="43.0">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField fx:id="rx" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="48.0">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="15.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField fx:id="comment" layoutX="63.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="557.0" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="673.0">
               <children>
                  <Region prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="504.0" />
                  <Button fx:id="save" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveButtonClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="Save">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="clear" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clearButtonClick" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="78.0" text="Clear" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </VBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

I am adding the data in the controller class. under saveButtonClick

Comment: `tableView.getItems().add(newItem);`??? You do want to add a new row, don't you?

Comment: yeah essentially, but when i do that, the addition does not show up. Ill edit the question with code.

Comment: You don't seem to add `cellValueFactory`s to the columns. Furthermore you should probably reconsider using `String` as item class in the `TableView`...

Comment: Could you provide me with an example syntax?